# How to transmit UIViewController by clicking on a button inside a .xib file with a class of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with few `TableViews`. Each cell is a .xib file with its own class inherited `UITableViewCell`. One of the cell has a button that is being used for logout.

what I need is: when I click the button, transmit the `viewController` to another view which is `loginViewController`.

the problem is: I have no access to `storyboard` and `navigationController` inside my `tableViewCell` class. (as below)

```
class ProfileCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func btnLogout(_ sender: Any) {

    //here I want to navigate to another view.

       //below is a sample when I use in viewController classes. but how to use it inside this class.

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginID") as! LoginViewController
        self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: “I have no access to storyboard and navigationController inside my tableViewCell class”  That doesn’t matter. The button is just a message sender. All that matters is when and how you give the button its target and action, and what that target is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `closure` too to achieve this :

In your `tableViewCell` :

```
class ProfileCell: UITableViewCell {

    var callBackOnButtonLogout: (()->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func btnLogout(_ sender: Any) {
        self.callBackOnButtonLogout?()
    }
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCell

    cell.callBackOnButtonLogout = {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginID") as! LoginViewController
        self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return cell 
}
```

Comment: And using closure is a nice solution. works perfectly. Thanks Amit.

Comment: I'm using your answer for now, so this is the accepted answer ;). However  I really like @Francesco Deliro answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate with the view controller using [delegation pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276):

> “Delegation is a design pattern that enables a class or structure to hand off (or delegate) some of its responsibilities to an instance of another type.”

For example:

```
protocol LogoutDelegate: class {
    func shouldLogout()
}

class ProfileCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var logoutDelegate: LogoutDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func btnLogout(_ sender: Any) {
        logoutDelegate?.shouldLogout()
    }

}
```

Then you have to adopt the protocol in your view controller and to set `cell.logoutDelegate = self`.

Comment: You can find a great explanation of how delegation works in this article: [Delegation in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift)